# Is it possible to get a return type from a keyup function?

Tags: javascript, jquery

My current code is this and what I'm trying to is see if I could get a return value after the key up is done.

```
$("#confirm").keyup(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    ajax_pass_check();

});
```

so I would end up with something like this because my `ajax_pass_check();` function returns true/false.

```
$("#confirm").keyup(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    return ajax_pass_check();

});
```

I would like to see if I could do that, and try something like

```
var one = $("#confirm").keyup(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    return ajax_pass_check();

});
```

I'm new to javascript and I've looked on google for awhile and I haven't found what I needed so I thought I'd ask. However when I did try that, I didn't get the expected result I was hoping for. Since `var one` remained `false`, when it should have been `true` after the function `ajax_pass_check();`

~edit: I took advice one of you guys (thanks for all the replies!) I still can't figure out why my `var one` variable false even though I set it to true in the keyup function.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var one = false;

    $("#confirm").keyup(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    one = ajax_pass_check();
    //one = true; //even if I do that it doesn't work.
    });

    if(one == true)
    {
        $('input[type="submit"]').removeAttr('disabled');
    }
    else
    {
        $('input[type="submit"]').attr('disabled','disabled');    
    }
});
```

Comment: You are in a good way. Only thing is that code inside functions will not run at the same time with code outside functions. You should check if your variable is true, inside a function.

Comment: @mavrosxristoforos, I think that after the keyup function, since var one is somewhat of a global variable, that my if/else check to see if `var one` is true or not, should work. Or am I missing something?

Comment: Your code is not running linear. The fact that it is below, doesn't mean it runs after it. If you want to do something **after** the event, you should add another function inside `keyUp`.

Comment: @SieuPhan as per my answer ;)

Comment: The thing is @mavrosxristoforos & jamesj, I have around 5-6 keyup function calls and I need to check if all of them return true (successful), and the only way that I can think I can do that is to do it after all of the function calls.

Comment: @SieuPhan That is another question. Maybe you should think about posting it as a new one, and accepting one of the answers here. A simple answer to your new question would possibly involve to do `one = one & ajax_pass_check();`, to keep the false value, and check it on another event.

Comment: @SieuPhan I agree with mavrosxistoforos. You can't do what you want in the way you are intending. Posting another question with the details of linking your keyup event handler functions might be more fruitful ;)

Comment: Thank you both of you guys/gals as well as many others but @jamesj had the most informative post, and sadly I can't accept yours too mavrosxistoforos but I'll give you an upvote since you did clear up some things, thanks again!

Comment: Looking at your function name (ajax_pass_check) you should also keep in mind that any Ajax calls are asynchronous. The keyup-function would be likely to return a value before your Ajax-call is complete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, but you could call another function to use the result of ajax_pass_check. For example,

```
$("#confirm").keyup(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    doSomethingElse(ajax_pass_check());

});

function doSomethingElse(keyUpOk) {   // Do something  ... }
```

Assuming (based on your function names) you are using this to do some form of validation this will allow you to display or clear an error message.

The reason you cant do

```
var one = $("#confirm").keyup(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    return ajax_pass_check();

});
```

is because the key up function is just binding you function to the event, so this code will have already been executed when the key is released. You will probably want to call a function so that something is done with the result of the keyup event handler after the keyup event is fired, not when you function is bound to the event.

Try this instead

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var one = false;

$("#confirm").keyup(function(event){
  event.preventDefault();
  one = ajax_pass_check();
  //one = true; //even if I do that it doesn't work.

  if(one == true)
  {
      $('input[type="submit"]').removeAttr('disabled');
  }
  else
  {
      $('input[type="submit"]').attr('disabled','disabled');    
  }
});
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of returning a value, you should consider using global scope for the variable, and set its desired value inside your function:

```
var wasSuccessful = false;

$("#confirm").keyup(function(event){
   event.preventDefault();
   your_function();
});

function yourfunction() {
  if your awesome code worked { wasSuccessful = true; }
  else { wasSuccessful = false; }
}
```

Comment: Every time you write `if (condition) { variable = true } else { variable = false }` God kills a kitten.

Comment: couldn't I just do, `wasSuccessful = your_function();` since the boolean variable will be a global if I do it this way

Comment: Yes you could, depence where. ;-)

Comment: @ArtyomNeustroev God is not involved into killing kittens (James 1:13, 2 Chronicles 16:9), and I suppose you obviously understand the simplification I made here.

Comment: @jamesj I added a snippet to OP to show how I edited according to the help provided, and it still doesn't change to true

Comment: @SieuPhan Then I would suggest that the problem lies in your ajax_pass_check function

Answer (score 0):

**The Answer is: No**

The jQuery Function keyup doesnt return a special value, only the jQuery Object [see the API](http://api.jquery.com/keyup/)(at the top), since it is used only to bind functions.

[image: screenshot]

Depence on what you want to achieve, one of the solutions, mentioned by the others could solve your issue.